# Can I use NSPopover in Xcode 6 and storyboard?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, storyboard

I tried to use `NSPopover` and its view controller in my Cocoa app, but I found that it is not available in Xcode 6 and storyboard environment. I did use it in my Cocoa app on Xcode 5.x. I can also use it on a project which originally was created under Xcode 6 but use nib and not use storyboard. However, the new project which is created in Xcode 6 with storyboard being on cannot find `NSPopover` in Object Library.

So how can I use NSPopover and its view controller in Xcode 6 project under storyboard?

Answer (score 3):

You create a general view controller then add a popover-type segue connection to it from one or more controls.

Comment: how? when I drag from that viewController to a NSMenuItem I don't see any popover option. I see modal, show and custom.

Comment: Menu items can't have popover segues.